# exec-maven-plugin want to pass maven.dependency.classpath as a variable in my EXEC Goal

Tags: maven-2, ant, maven, maven-3, exec-maven-plugin

```
I want to define property or want to use maven.plugin.classpath and maven.dependency.classpath in my build.xml.

How can i do it ?

Sample code is as below...

<property> </property> is not working and not able to read the values from my build.xml so please explain me how can i do it ?


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                    <property name="maven_dependency_classpath" refid="maven.dependency.classpath" />               
                    <executable>antscript.bat</executable> <!-- ant -f build.xml build -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



Hi Sean Patrick Floyd,


Yes i tried using maven-antrun-plugin but i am not able to setup JDK 1.4.2 version in it. I am trying to specify all possible way to apply JDK version 1.4.2 but it's still taking tools.jar or JDK version, Which maven.bat file is using (jdk 1.5)

I was using following code in MAVEN-ANTRUN-PLUGIN as below code.

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java-version}</source>
                            <target>${java-version}</target>
                            <compilerVersion>${java-version}</compilerVersion>
                            <executable>${java.1.4.2.home}/bin/javac</executable>
                             <target>

                                <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                                <property name="maven_dependency_classpath" refid="maven.dependency.classpath" />
                                <ant antfile="ant_build.xml" />
                             </target>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.2</version>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                        <systemPath>${java.1.4.2.home}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
                        <version>${java-version}</version>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                        <systemPath>${java.1.4.2.home}/jre/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>



That's why i choose exec GOAL where my SYSTEM JAVA_HOME is 1.4.2 and it's able to execute it if i have all dependencies which i needed.


Please help me out.






Thanks.
```

Answer (score 1):

`maven.plugin.classpath` etc. are variables defined in the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) only. The exec plugin doesn't know about these values. Also, it wouldn't be possible to do it like that in the first place, as you are calling an external .bat file and hence starting a new process.

If I were you I'd use the antrun plugin. See [the usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) for details.

---

**Update:** ok, now I see your problem. No, you can't use a different JDK, since antrun works within the same vm. So either you need to switch the JDK maven uses, or you do in fact need to use the exec-maven-plugin. In the latter case, you will have to use
[`dependency:build-classpath -DoutputFile=someFile.txt`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html)
and on the ant side, read the contents of `someFile.txt` as a property and create a classpath from it. Or you can [use the `%classpath` variable placeholder](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html) in your command line args.

Comment: @user886614 Would it be possible to use the maven-antrun-plugin to invoke an Ant <exec> task with the need Java environment? You could use the maven classpath properties available in the antrun plugin to supply dependency jar locations to the <exec> task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes correct answer which i found is to Use MAVEN version which supports JDK 1.4.2. So i have to use apache-maven-2.0.11 which supports JDK 1.4.2

Thanks all for your answers.